# When should I set a texture as a shader resource in order to read it?

Tags: c#, textures, shaders, directx11, sharpdx

I'm writing a Direct3D 11 HLSL shader with SharpDX. What I want to do is write the depth to a texture in one pass and read it in the next one. After declaring the texture, do I have to set the depth texture and the shader resource view per frame, or just once when attaching?

```
this.depthStencilShaderResourceVariable = this.effect.GetVariableByName("DepthTexture").AsShaderResource();
this.depthStencilShaderResourceVariable.SetResource(this.depthTextureShaderResourceView);
```

Comment: I'm not certain about DirectX, but in OpenGL you aren't allowed to render to a bound texture - so some rebinding is necessary each frame.

Comment: Ok, but what do you mean by bound texture? I thought the bindings I'm doing there were precisely to be able to read the texture.

Comment: You can't read and write a texture simultaneously in the common case.  So you have to bind the depth texture to write it, then unbind it for writing before you bind it for reading.  There are ways around this for regular textures using newer hardware features, but not for depth textures to my knowledge.

Comment: Thanks, so I guess the changes I have to do are per frame?

Answer (score 1):

D3D11 will prevent you from binding a shader view of a resource *and* a render view of a resource simultaneously.

Consequently you will need to bind and unbind the views every time you want to read or write to the depth texture; you can't just bind them and leave them that way for the lifetime of your program, because you can't have both views bound simultaneously.

Comment: Actually, if you want to write a bound texture, D3D11 will unbind it for you while generating a warning: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/88373/can-state-setting-warnings-be-ignored

Comment: Huh, that's interesting, I'd never tried that since the documentation is littered with comments about the "conflict checker" that "prevents" this sort of thing. Good to know.